# Clicking back button is giving illegal state exception

Tags: blackberry

In my application, when i am clicking i showing a dialog. and when i am pressing yes in that Dialog, it is giving me the illegal state exception. But i want to go back in the previous screen. If i am clicking menu and clicking close, then it is going back to the previous screen. Below is my code:

```
 public boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time) {

        if (Keypad.KEY_ESCAPE == Keypad.key(keycode)) {
            int result = Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_YES_NO, "Do you want to edit the list?");
            if (result == Dialog.YES) 
            {
                try
                {
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(this);
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
//              onClose();
            } 
            else 
            {
                return true;
            }
        } // end if

        return false;
    }
```

Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are clicking the back button in the device then default **onclose()** method is called. So, try to do like this;

```
protected boolean onSavePrompt() 
{
    return true;
}
public boolean onClose() 
{
    int choose=Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_YES_NO, "Close the screen?");
    if(choose==Dialog.YES)
    {
        return super.onClose();
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is the better way; If you use like the above one then you may get one problem; That is:

> If you are using that method in the first screen then according to your code when popup the screen then there is no screen in the display stack(**Because it is the first screen**); So you may get this type of problem;

Try this one;

Comment: @Arindam Mukherjee: some times if you want sudden requirement come to this chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java